What is the "normal form" of a $\Pi^1_1$ sentence in a finite language for a suitable ordinal, according to Richter and Aczel?
In "Inductive Definitions and Reflecting Properties of Admissible Ordinals" by Richter and Aczel, on page 39 they make a claim that $\Pi^1_1$-sentences in the language of $\in$ along with another finitary relation symbol can be put into a "normal form."
Specifically they claim that if $\phi$ is our sentence, we can construct a new sentence $\phi'=\forall f\exists\xi:Q(f,\xi)$, where $Q$ is a quantifier-free first-order formula with $f$ appearing as a relation symbol (rather than as a function symbol used to construct terms, so in particular $f$ is not nested), so that for structures of the kind $(\alpha;\in, R_1...R_n)$ where $\alpha$ is any ordinal closed under the standard pairing operation, we have
$$(\alpha;\in, R_1...R_n)\models\phi\leftrightarrow\phi'$$.
$Q$ is meant to be in a language that is slightly expanded from that of the structure, consisting of some pairing relationships.
They cite the textbook "Theory of recursive functions and effective
computability" by Rogers as justification, claiming that in the textbook they perform a similar normalization for $\Pi^1_1$ sets in the analytical hierarchy. Looking through this text however, I was unable to find such a part (much of the text was beyond my grasp).
How is it that Richter and Aczel are getting $\phi'$ out of $\phi$?

This is (some version of) the Kleene normal form theorem for $\Pi^1_1$ relations. Have a look at Sacks's book Higher Recursion Theory, theorem 1.3 on pages 4–5. It's freely available on Project Euclid.

Thanks. After looking at the text you provided, I also found the same theorem in Simpson's SOSA, stated in a way that was easier for my newbie brain to comprehend. Cheers

Yes, it's in there too (lemma V.1.4 on page 169 of the 2nd edition, in case it's useful for anyone else). Simpson's proofs can sometimes be a little opaque if one isn't already familiar with the computability-theoretic result that they're formalising, but this one is ok. Another treatment, from a descriptive set theory angle, is in chapter 3 of Mansfield and Weitkamp's book Recursive Aspects of Descriptive Set Theory (Oxford University Press, 1985). That's the one I tend to give to students, although the book is somewhat hard to come by.
